# Small double addition seemingly not working in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double BASE = 0.4527210187492833;
    double num = 0.4527210187492833;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        num+=2.7755575615628914E-17;
    }

    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(BASE == num);
}
```

}

prints
`0.4527210187492833 true`

Shouldn't this print 0.4527210187492833 + (1000000000 * 2.7755575615628914E-17) ≈ 0.4527210465 -> false?

Comment: Looks like the closest possible float to `BASE + 2.7755575615628914E-17` is BASE. That's floating points for you.

Comment: [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)